# JavaScript - Play audio along with randomly generated values

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, random

I have a function that displays a random word from an array, in a non-repeated way.

I would also like to play a sound clip with each word (that sound would be the word's pronounciation).

I know how to play single sounds, and how to play random sounds from an array of sounds. But if I create an array of sounds, how can I play each one only when the corresponding word is displayed?

This is what I am working with:

```js
const p = document.getElementById("randomWord");
const origWords = ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo"];
const audioClips = ["alpha.mp3", "bravo.mp3", "charlie.mp3", "delta.mp3", "echo.mp3"];
let remainingWords = [];

function randomize() {
  if (remainingWords.length === 0) remainingWords = origWords.slice();
  const {
    length
  } = remainingWords;
  const [word] = remainingWords.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * length), 1);
  p.textContent = word;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="randomize()" type="button">Random Word</button>
<p id="randomWord"></p>
```

Comment: use the words as key and sounds as value in an object . then select one of them random and show key as word and play value for sound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the way you store your data. Instead of `origWords` and `audioClips` you could use an Array of Objects:

```
const myWords = [
    {
       text: "alpha",
       audio: "alpha.mp3"
    },
    {
       text: "bravo",
       audio: "bravo.mp3"
    },
    ...
]
```

Then in your function after you get the random index just acces the `.text` or `.audio` keys

Edit: Snippet

```js
const p = document.getElementById("randomWord");
const myWords = [
    {
       text: "alpha",
       audio: "alpha.mp3"
    },
    {
       text: "bravo",
       audio: "bravo.mp3"
    }
 ];
 let remainingWords = [];

function randomize() {
  if (remainingWords.length === 0) remainingWords = myWords.slice();
  let length = remainingWords.length;
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  const word = remainingWords[randomIndex];
  remainingWords.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  console.log(word);
  console.dir(p);
  p.textContent = word.text;
// your audio code here like audio.play(word.audio);
}
```

```html
    <button onclick="randomize()" type="button">Random Word</button>
    <p id="randomWord"></p>
```

Comment: I replaced the two arrays for an array of objects like that. But after that I got a bit lost. I am still learning JS. Could you please show me an examplpe of what I should be doing next?

Comment: The words show up, but I have no sound... Is it supposed to play automatically when the text is displayed? Do I need an extra function to play the sounds along?

Comment: @distance Also, I stopped getting non-repeated words, which I would like to keep.

Comment: @MikeMichaels Ah! well just edit the code to your convenience I just edited quick to make an example of how to access Objects Key/value pairs. And yes you have to make the play sound javascript.

Comment: I know how to play sound with `audio.play();`, but is that the way to do it here? What can I change in the code to make the sound play automatically when each random word is displayed?

Comment: `audio.play(word.audio)`

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you again with something that is probably pretty basic, but where should I put that? I tried at the end of the `randomize()` function, at the end of the whole script, in the button, after `onclick=randomize()`... But nothing seems to work.

Comment: I managed to make it work. Thank you a lot for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an hashmap, for example:

```
const origWords = {"alpha":"alpha.mp3", "bravo":"bravo.mp3", "charlie":"charlie.mp3", "delta":"delta.mp3", "echo":"echo.mp3"};

...    

randomIndex = randomize();
key = Object.keys(origWords)[randomIndex];
p.textContent = key;
playSound(origWords[key]);
...
```